docker + wordpress + nginx = intermittent 404
edit: fixed; answer below
My Dockerized wordpress website is having reliability issues all of a sudden
monitoring with uptime-kuma gives intermittent 404 errors
accessing the root webpage after a "docker compose up -d" gives first a 200 then 404 then if I keep refreshing I get either so the website is dropping connections
I tried restarting server; chown everything to www-data (I know it not good but im desperate) and even upgrading the vps to rule out potential bottlenecks but nothing is working and my client is complaining
here is /var/logs/nginx/access.log below. error.log shows no error. How can I have 200 and 404 intermittently ? that makes no sense to me.
xx.xx.187.3 - - [07/Jun/2024:11:48:55 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 200 22186 "https://website.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.5 Safari/605.1.15"
xx.xx.187.3 - - [07/Jun/2024:11:49:02 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 404 22186 "https://website.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.5 Safari/605.1.15"
66.249.69.136 - - [07/Jun/2024:11:49:02 +0000] "GET /index.phpfproduct/jtauntu1871211?id=563 HTTP/1.1" 200 157689 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.6422.168 Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
xx.xx.187.3 - - [07/Jun/2024:11:49:05 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 47 "https://website.com/wp-admin/plugin-install.php?s=cache&tab=search&type=term" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.5 Safari/605.1.15"

weirdly enough website/wp-admin seems to be working just fine
nginx.conf:
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name website www.website;

        location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
                allow all;
                root /var/www/html;
        }

        location / {
                rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
        }
}

server {
        # listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;
        http2 on;
        server_name website www.website;

        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        root /var/www/html;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        server_tokens off;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/website/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/website/privkey.pem;

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/options-ssl-nginx.conf;

        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
        add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade" always;
        add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src * data: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'" always;
        # add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;
        # enable strict transport security only if you understand the implications

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass wordpress:9000;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }

        location = /favicon.ico {
                log_not_found off; access_log off;
        }
        location = /robots.txt {
                log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all;
        }
        location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
        }
}

and options-ssl.nginx
ssl_session_cache shared:le_nginx_SSL:10m;
ssl_session_timeout 1440m;
ssl_session_tickets off;

ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;

ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-....

docker-compose
version: '3.3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: db
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: $MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
      MYSQL_DATABASE: $MYSQL_DATABASE
      MYSQL_USER: $MYSQL_USER
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: $MYSQL_PASSWORD
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
      - "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro"
    command: "--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password"
    networks:
      - app-network

  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:6.5.3-fpm
    container_name: wordpress
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: $MYSQL_USER
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: $MYSQL_PASSWORD
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: $MYSQL_DATABASE
    volumes:
      - wordpress_data:/var/www/html
      - ./settings/php/custom.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/custom.ini
      - "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro"
    networks:
      - app-network

  webserver:
    container_name: nginx
    image: nginx:latest
    restart: always
    env_file: .env
    ports:
        - "80:80"
        - "443:443"
        - "25:25"
        - "587:587"
        - "465:465"
    volumes:
      - /var/log/nginx/:/var/log/nginx/
      - wordpress_data:/var/www/html
      - ./settings/nginx-conf/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./settings/nginx-conf/options-ssl-nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/options-ssl-nginx.conf
      - certbot-etc:/etc/letsencrypt
      - "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro"
    networks:
      - app-network
    depends_on:
      - wordpress


  certbot:
    depends_on:
      - webserver
    image: certbot/certbot
    container_name: certbot
    volumes:
      - certbot-etc:/etc/letsencrypt
      - wordpress_data:/var/www/html
      - "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro"
    command: certonly --webroot --webroot-path=/var/www/html --email user@domain.com --agree-tos --no-eff-email --force-renewal -d website -d www.website



volumes:
  dbdata:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: 'none'
      o: 'bind'
      device: '/var/www/database'
  wordpress_data:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: 'none'
      o: 'bind'
      device: '/var/www/html'
  certbot-etc:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: 'none'
      o: 'bind'
      device: '/var/www/certbot'

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge


are these Nginx 404s or WordPress 404s? Does this happen just with WordPress or with static assets/HTML files? Note that the wordpress image is not official and doesn't come from wordpress. It's official in the sense that Docker themselves created it as an example and maintain it, but they did this with no input from the WordPress project.

So Im posting the answer if that helps anyone. It turns out all my issues where coming from a failed wordpress auto update to 6.5.4. after forcing the update everything came back to normal
